# display alert inside Async doinbackground in android

Tags: android

In my android application i am using a loading screen,processed by Async task.In do in background of this task i would like to display a alert whenever an upgraded version exist in the server.
Could you please let me know if there is any way that i can do it in android.

The code is

> public class Task extends AsyncTask {

```
    // can use UI thread here
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // this.dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        prgbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        // this.dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
                final UpGradation upgrade=(UpGradation) ParserServiceImpl.getUpgrade(); //check this method name correctly.
                if(upgrade != null)
                {

                    try {
                        pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.docomo.aptv", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
                        String temp = pInfo.versionName;
                       int pversion= pInfo.versionCode;
                       int upversion=Integer.parseInt(upgrade.getVersion());
                       Log.i("VALUE RETURNED",""+pversion);
                        Log.i("jayantha","version name"+pInfo.versionName);
                        Log.i("jayanth","version code"+pInfo.versionCode);

                       if(pversion!=upversion)
                        {

                            final AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
                            alert.setTitle("Updates");
                            alert.setMessage("An updated version of the application is present.Do you wish to download.");

                             alert.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                    alert.dismiss();
                                        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
                                        i.setData(Uri.parse(upgrade.getURL().trim())); 
                                        startActivity(i); 
                                        finish();

                                   } }); 
                             alert.setButton2("Cancel",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(
                                                    DialogInterface dialog,
                                                    int which) {
                                                return;
                                            }
                                        });

                            alert.setIcon(R.drawable.application_icon_50x50);
                            alert.setCancelable(false);
                            alert.show();


                           }
                      } 


                     catch (NameNotFoundException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

Please forward your suggestions.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot show alerts and dialogs from to doInBackground() method. us the postProgress() and do it in the onProgressUpdate() or wait for the afterExecuted() to do those things from the main UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

you have `finish()` your current activity before showing the Alert. and you have navigated to another activity too... that is the problem here.

check this code snippet. it appears before showing the alert.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
i.setData(Uri.parse(upgrade.getURL().trim())); 
startActivity(i); 
finish();
```

Comment: Sorry it was placed for testing.Please check the code now.Its edited.